# How I can copy triangle shape numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, copy, triangle-count

I am solving some questions in Python and I am beginner level. I wonder how I can copy number that I found on internet. When I try to copy triangle shape number like:

[75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65 I added the shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMNxE.png)

I cant work with them in Python.It gives error invalid syntax on end of second line. I need to turn them to a list. In the example it is short enough to do myself but it can be 1000 numbers. Is there any function or something for do that. I know it is so easy think to ask but I cannot find it and I am beginner.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: I am trying to solve Project Euler Prob. 18 and I need the numbers of triangle in my Idle to coding it is 15 line triangle and problem 67 will be 100 I can't separate all number with "," myself is there any simple way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

string = r"""
23 17\n
98 """


ans = re.findall("\d+", string, re.MULTILINE)
list_int = [int(i) for i in ans]

print(ans) # ['23', '17', '98']
print(list_int) # [23, 17, 98]
```

I think you could try something like that, because it appears some text encoding problem, and with this snippet you can get just numbers from a copy and paste string.

Comment: Thank you it will be enough to go on with for now but still I need to write /n to end of lines. When numbers of the line will be 100 or 1000 it will be same situation again.

Comment: I don't understand, if you could explain in a different way, maybe with some example I could understand it better. And if you want to keep `\n` you could change regex to `"\d+\n*"`

Comment: the last thing you mentioned is enough thank you for your help.